# Show custom post type under last posts configuration

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I am looking for a way to display a custom post type or posts on my main page, which should be configured under the last post type section in settings.

I tried the following:

```
add_filter( 'widget_posts_args', 'recent_posts_args');

function recent_posts_args($args) {
    $args['post_type'] = array('post', 'custom Post Type');
    return $args;
}
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong? I guess it is the `widget_posts_args` argument, but I am not sure what else to use instead?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: The `widget_posts_args` filter will allow you to show custom post types inside the recent posts widget. Is that what you're after?

Comment: @DaveRomsey I would like to show the posts not in the widget, but directly on the website. Are there any other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `custom Post Type` there with your real custom post type name:

```
  $args['post_type'] = array('post', 'custom Post Type');
```